# Inserting hebrew characters in prepared statement

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic, hebrew

I understand that when I hard code an insert statement with hebrew in it, it works to add N' before the words , keeps the correct characters in

But now i have a prepared statement in ASP .
where am I supposed to put that 'N.
If I put it with the prepared part, it puts it as part of the text itself,

```vb
 MM_editCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE CampOnlineApps SET CamperFirstName = ? ...."
 MM_editCmd.Parameters.Append MM_editCmd.CreateParameter("param1", 202, 1, 30, Request.Form("camperFirstName")) ' adVarWChar
```

Here's the start of my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `N'` part as you already tell the prepared statement to use `adVarWChar` *(`202`)*. If it isn't working what data type is the field `CamperFirstName` set to?, it will need to be `NVARCHAR(...)`.

Comment: The database is set up NVARCHAR. but the text is coming through &*x~x~x

Comment: Can you check the value of `Request.Form("camperFirstName")` before you pass it to the query, it might be encoded wrong before it hits the prepared statement. Use `Response.Write Request.Form("camperFirstName") : Response.End` to test the input.

Comment: when i do a response.write, it comes out properly in hebrew.

Comment: So you are using Classic ASP. What charset is the page set to use?

Comment: Your input is utf-8, asp classic does not handle this by default. that's as mush as I know about asp but you can try to follow from here.

Comment: The hebrew works on a page when I put a regular insert statement with 'N. It doesn't work on my prepared statement.

Comment: Can you share some code, especially the `head` part of the HTML?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">